# What is the utility of specifying Versions in use_flipper()

Tags: ios, react-native, podfile

I'm working on a react-native application, inside iOS/podfile are specified the versions of some packages :

```
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.

  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
```

I'm wondering what is the utility of specifying the packages versions here ? It seems to be important since I encounter issues whenever I remove this but I might be stuck if I try to upgrade those packages any day.

Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a function in react-native's [react_native_pods.rb](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/scripts/react_native_pods.rb) Ruby script.
It is located in `node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb`.

[**react-native v0.69.6**](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.69.6/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L158)

```
def use_flipper!(versions = {}, configurations: ['Debug'])
  versions['Flipper'] ||= '0.125.0'
  versions['Flipper-Boost-iOSX'] ||= '1.76.0.1.11'
  versions['Flipper-DoubleConversion'] ||= '3.2.0.1'
  versions['Flipper-Fmt'] ||= '7.1.7'
  versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '2.6.10'
  versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.5.0.5'
  versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] ||= '0.0.4'
  versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '1.4.3'
  versions['OpenSSL-Universal'] ||= '1.1.1100'
  pod 'FlipperKit', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  # List all transitive dependencies for FlipperKit pods
  # to avoid them being linked in Release builds
  pod 'Flipper', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-Boost-iOSX', versions['Flipper-Boost-iOSX'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-DoubleConversion', versions['Flipper-DoubleConversion'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-Fmt', versions['Flipper-Fmt'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-Folly', versions['Flipper-Folly'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-Glog', versions['Flipper-Glog'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-PeerTalk', versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'Flipper-RSocket', versions['Flipper-RSocket'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/Core', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/CppBridge', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FBDefines', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin', versions['Flipper'], :configurations => configurations
  pod 'OpenSSL-Universal', versions['OpenSSL-Universal'], :configurations => configurations
end
```

[**react-native v0.70.3**](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.70.3/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L139)

```
def use_flipper!(versions = {}, configurations: ['Debug'])
  Pod::UI.warn "use_flipper is deprecated, use the flipper_configuration option in the use_react_native function"
  use_flipper_pods(versions, :configurations => configurations)
end
```

The content of the file may vary depending on the version of react-native you are using.